# Edit Links is missing in quick launch in SharePoint 2013

Tags: quick-launch, edit-links

I have multipe subsites, but one of them is not showing the Edit Link in quick launch.

This is the information about the site:

- it uses Team Site template (STS 1)
- I have checked the permissions and they are the same as in other sites
- it inherits from the parent site
- it is not hidden by css or javascript
- at one point the permission inheritance was broken but was restored back to inheriting from the parent
- Navigation settings in Site settings are the same as in other sites

Any help?

Comment: Did you find any fix?

Answer (score 1):

If site is created with blank or publishing template, you will not see EDIT link option. Below mentioned template are supported.

STS#0",
            "SPSMSITEHOST#0",
            "SPSPERS#0",
            "SPSPERS#2",
            "SPSPERS#3",
            "SPSPERS#4",
            "SPSPERS#5",
            "PROJECTSITE#0"

Comment: It is not true because the other subsites are created based on blank template (STS 1), but Edit links are visible there. There are 10 subsites which are based on STS1, but only one of them does not show the Edit Links in quick launch.

Comment: Ok..so every site is based on same template..thats interesting! So quick launch is available but not Edit links option? Can you compare DOM elements from two different sites in developer toolbar. any CSS there? (I understand u mentioned there is no css, but just to make sure)